# not able to get all the emails from facebook OAuth

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-oauth

I am working on facebook OAuth. I am able to get some of the emails from facebook accounts while some of them are not coming.

what can be the issue.

```
 function login() {
        FB.init({
            appId: '<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["facebookAPI"].ToString() %>',
            cookie: true,
            status: true, xfbml: true
        });
        FB.login(function (response) {
            //alert("login");
            //if (response.session) {
            if (response) {
                //alert(response);
                //alert("login");
                var url = '/me?fields=name,email';
                FB.api(url, function (response) {

                    //var image = 'http://graph.facebook.com/' + response.id + '/picture';

                    // alert(response.name);
                    //alert(response.email);
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "Login.aspx/SaveFacebookAutoSignUp",
                        data: "{ 'Name':'" + response.name + "', 'EmailId': '" + response.email + "'}",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data) {
                            // alert("You have successfully sign in.Please Wait, we redirect you in a second.");
                            window.location = '<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["weburl"].ToString() %>' + "OAuth.aspx?userId=" + data.d;
                        }

                    });

                });

            }
        });
    }
```

Please see the code, this is what i have done, what can be the issue??

Please let me know if require more details.

Answer (score 1):

The email details are provided based on the privacy setting of the user.If the user has set his email address as not to be publicly revealed then Facebook doesn't fetch such data.

Its all based on the permissions and privacy settings.

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution....

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/

they have change some settings.

```
FB.login(function(response) {   // handle the response }, {scope: 'email,user_likes'});
```

**{scope: 'email,user_likes'}**
works for me :)